# Fibronacci sequence spitting wrong number

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, math, fibonacci

I have created a function that sumbs up all odd fibronacci numbers up to a given number, and for the most part it works all for except one number.  For example sumFibs(10) should return 10 becuz all Fib #s <= 10 are 1,1,3 and 5.

If I do sumFibs(75024); I get 135721 instead of the expected value is 60696. For every other number it works perfectly and am scratching my head to solve it

```js
function sumFibs(num) {

  let thunderAss = [];
  let currDmp = 0;
  let nxtRmp = 1;
  var pushNxt = 0;
  // push into array
  for (let x = 0; x < num; x++) {
    if (x <= 1) {
      console.log("lets go");
      thunderAss.push(1); // 2l almond milk
    } else {
      thunderAss.push(thunderAss[x - 1] + thunderAss[x - 2]);
      console.log(x, " x is factor");
    }
  }
  console.log(thunderAss);

  let cuntNuts = 0;
  for (let x = 0; x < num; x++) {
    if (cuntNuts < num) {
      if (thunderAss[x] % 2 == 0) {} else {
        cuntNuts += thunderAss[x];
      }
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log("CN: ", cuntNuts);
  return cuntNuts;
}
sumFibs(75024); // 60696 but 135721
sumFibs(4);
```

Comment: "sumFibs(10) should return 10 becuz all Fib #s <= 10 are 1,1,3 and 5."  Shouldn't 2 and 8 also be included? And return 20? 1,1,2,3,5,8

Comment: When you write "becuz", do you mean "because"?

Comment: no you are only adding the odd numbers

Comment: sorry for my english i am danish

Comment: Judging by the vulgarity in variable names you got at least that aspect of English down cold.

Comment: @freedomCoder. And I'm Swedish.

Comment: Instead of the `if (x <= 1)` condition in the loop, just initialize the array with the first two elements, and start the loop at `x = 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `if (cuntNuts < num)` is wrong. `cuntNuts` is the sum of fibonacci numbers, not the fibonacci number itself. So you're stopping when the sum reaches `n`, not summing all the odd numbers up to `n`.

You should be comparing `thunderAss[x]` with `num`. And it should be `<=` if that number should be included in the total.

You can also put this condition into the `for` loop header rather than adding it as a separate check in the body.

```js
function sumFibs(num) {

  let thunderAss = [];
  let currDmp = 0;
  let nxtRmp = 1;
  var pushNxt = 0;
  // push into array
  for (let x = 0; x < num; x++) {
    if (x <= 1) {
      console.log("lets go");
      thunderAss.push(1); // 2l almond milk
    } else {
      thunderAss.push(thunderAss[x - 1] + thunderAss[x - 2]);
      console.log(x, " x is factor");
    }
  }
  console.log(thunderAss);

  let cuntNuts = 0;
  for (let x = 0; thunderAss[x] <= num; x++) {
    if (thunderAss[x] % 2 == 0) {} else {
      cuntNuts += thunderAss[x];
    }
  }
  console.log("CN: ", cuntNuts);
  return cuntNuts;
}
sumFibs(75024); // 60696 but 135721
sumFibs(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `num` first Fibonacci numbers instead of the Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to `num`.

In my solution here, I do the correct thing and get the correct answer:

```js
function* fibonacci()
{
    let x = 0;
    let y = 1;

    while (true) {
        yield x;
        [x, y] = [y, x+y];
    }
}


function sum_odd_fibonacci(max)
{
    const fib_seq = fibonacci();

    let s = 0;
    let n;
    while ( (n=fib_seq.next().value) <= max) {
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            s += n;
        }
    }

    return s;
}


console.log(sum_odd_fibonacci(75024));
```